# Left Align within Centered Div

Tags: html, css

I have a outer div that has a `text-align : center;` primarily to force equal spacing between right and left borders as `margin-left: auto;` & `margin-right:auto;` doesn't do it!. How do i get the div's within the outer div to left align instead of center-align? Here is a example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/5/ where the third box needs to be positioned below the first box?

```
.bor{
    border:1px solid;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px dotted;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Must `.outer` be a fixed width? How about http://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/2/

Comment: Hi @George, So the width is 100%.My bad i should have used it in my question. I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/3/ to show you the issue. The spacing is unequal between left/right outer borders. and so nth-child(2n-1) can't be used i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use percentage widths and margins to maintain equal spacing?

```
.bor{
    border:1px solid;
    width:40%;
    height:100px;
    margin:5%;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px dotted;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:2%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/1/

Comment: Hi @Styphon, It's mandatory that inner div be fixed width & height of 100px irrespective of outer div width. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove text-align:center for parent div and use padding for the outer div.  For data inside the child div you can use

```
.outer .bor { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Had a look at your fiddle and the parent container will center all its child elements e.g. 'divs'. What I would recommend is you either set padding in your outer container to bring the inner divs in more or set a float left on the 3rd element you want to sit below the first.

Either solution is down to you and your needs in the end here is an example.

**Float Solution**

https://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/

```
.bor{
    border:1px solid;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px dotted;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Padding Solution**

https://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/

```
.bor{
    border:1px solid;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px dotted;
    padding:20px;
}
```

**Percentage solution**

https://jsfiddle.net/3mb4to76/1/

```
.bor{
    border:1px solid;
    width:45%;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:25px
}
.bor:first-of-type {
    margin-right:10%;
}
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px dotted;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:2%;
}
```

You could also use the `:nth-child();` element to always target the first box or the second whatever your choosing

Hope this resolves your problem!

Comment: Hi @Harry Berry, None of this resolves the issue of having same space between left and right outer margin.

Comment: OK. If it has to be pixel values why not do some good old mathematics so you have a box which is '300px' wide and two which are '100px' wide give the outer box 'padding:0 50px;' and that will create the even space at both sides because '100+100+50+50 = 300'. This way the third box will react the same as the first two if floated to the left etc.

Comment: the problem with that is the width can be varying so I cant specify padding for all possible widths!